# How to declare functions with normal syntax and use children in react with TS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know that it can be typed in several ways, two of them using the interface `React.FC<YourInterface>` or declaring explicitly in an interface the type of *children* as *JSX.Element* or *React.Node*. So far I have to do this:

`const MyComponent: React.FC<MyInterface> = function({ x, children }) {} export default Mycomponent`

By normal syntax I mean `export default function Foo({ x, children })`. Without first having to declare a constant or variable. I've already tried with `function Foo({ x, children }): React.FC<MyInterface>` but TS transpiler gives error.

All tutorials I've seen are few and always use the arrow function syntax. I just feel more comfortable using the normal syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with `export default function () {...}` you can make use of type assertion with the `as` keyword. Remember about parentheses.

```
export default (function () {
  return 1 + 1;
} as () => number);
```

And react example:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  text: string;
}

export default (function ({ text, children }) {
  return <div></div>;
} as React.FC<Props>);
```

However in my opinion it's better to:

- type parameters and returning value, or
- create a variable and do normal type assertion on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood what you’re trying to do, but maybe this could work

```
export default function Foo(props: YourInterface): JSX.Element {}
```

Comment: I have already tried that, also with `React.FC`, but the TS transpiler gives error and also my code editor linter remarks "children has any type implicit"

Comment: Not at my desk right now but if you try adding React.FC as the retuned type instead of JSX.Element?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for non-arrow functional component:

```
interface YourInterface {
  x: string
}

export default function Foo({
  x,
  children,
}: React.PropsWithChildren<YourInterface>) {}
```

**I've already tried with function Foo({ x, children }): React.FC but TS transpiler gives error.**

**ans:** Because your component is a function that does not return `JSX`, it returns a functional component.